# vb.net: How to assign values to a list of variables dynamically

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

I have a gridview which is populated from a datasource, as such:

```
   Date              Hours
 January/2016        26.31
 January/2016        25.65
 February/2016       12.3
   ....          ...     ....
```

From that table I check for the weeks every month had and count them, so I can get an average later on, this is my code.

```
For intMonth = 1 To 12
    For X = 0 To GridView.Rows.Count - 1

        intDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gvTiempos.Rows(X).Cells(0).Text)

        If DatePart("m", intDate) = intMonth Then
            Calcular()            
        End If

      Next
Next
```

This is the `Calcular()` function:

```
Public Function Calcular()
 Select Case intMonth
   Case 1: JanWeeks+=1
   Case 2: FebWeeks+=1
    ...
   Case 12: DecWeeks+=1
```

What I would like to do is to avoid the whole `Calcular()` function, and do it "dynamically".

In other words, I would like to get something like this:

```
 Weeks(intMonth) = "Sum of Weeks for that month"
```

Where intMonth determinate in which WeekVariable the Sum will be storaged.
I have tried with the `List(Of T)` method unsuccessfully, because this creates a list of variables with a static value, according to my understanding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use a dictionary `colMonths(intMonth) +=1` If you have a data source you should use that rather than the control.  You could probably eveb write a linq query and get all 12(?) results at once.  It also looks like you should turn on Option Strict

Comment: You're probably better off to use an array. Then just use `Weeks(intMonth) = Weeks(intMonth) + 1`. On a side note, you can eliminate this line: `intDate = GridView.Rows(X).Cells(0).Text`. It's value is not being used and you are reassigning it on the next line.

Comment: @Icemanind yep ypu are right about that line, just edited the code, was a misspelled line.
About the `Weeks(intMonth) = Weeks(intMonth) + 1` it throwed this error:  
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @abichango - Did you declare it? : `Dim Weeks(12) As Integer`

Comment: @Plutonix could you explain a bit more on the dictonary method, I did look for it prior to my question but couldnt quite understand it.  
About the Option Strict its a huge project in which I was barely involved and I don't know what issues will come up with the other forms, if I turn it on :/

Comment: @Icemanind wow that was it, I had it declare with my previous attemp of `Dim Weeks as New List(of Integer)(12)`, can't belive it's that easy, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation in your comments, you should be able to simply do this:

```
Dim Weeks(12) As Integer
```

Then replace your call to `Calcular()` to this:

```
If DatePart("m", intDate) = intMonth Then
    Weeks(intMonth) = Weeks(intMonth) + 1
End If
```

This creates an array to hold the sum for each month in the year (12 months).

Answer (score 1):

Given a DataTable `dt` as the `DataSource` and cell/item 1 (not 0) has the formatted date, you can create a `Dictionary(of Int32, Int32)` to hold the count for each month.  Iterating the table should be faster than poking around the control; besides, the `DataTable` is where the data is.

```
Dim col As New Dictionary(Of Int32, Int32)
' create 12 keys for 12 months
For n As Int32 = 1 To 12
    col.Add(n, 0)
Next

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    col(Convert.ToDateTime(row(1)).Month) += 1
Next
```

Some slots will be zero, because the code added them all ahead of time.  A `List(Of Int32)` would also work using `MonthList(n)` to represent the month N-1.  You can also just query the table, group and count in one line:

```
Dim monthCount = dt.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(Function(v) v.Field(Of DateTime)(1).Month,
                            Function(k, v) New With {.Month = k, .Count = v.Count()}).
                       ToArray()
```

In this case, the result is a succinct list with the month and count (my date list was: `{#1/11/2016#, #1/23/2016#, #1/16/2016#, #2/11/2016#, #4/15/2016#}`):

[image]